# MVC Entity Framework Conundrum: "missing using directive or an assembley reference?"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4

This project used to work. I fuddled with the connection string in Web.Config trying to get it to work with .accdb file. Forget that.
But now I can't get back home to a working project.

HomeController.cs code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using oesac.Models;


namespace oesac.Controllers
{
    [HandleError]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {


     oesacEntities_connection _db;



        public HomeController()
        {

        _db = new oesacEntities_connection();


        }
```

=============================

E:\oesac_MVC\Controllers\HomeController.cs(52,42): error CS1061: 'oesac.Models.oesacEntities_connection' does not contain a definition for 'Courses' and no extension method 'Courses' accepting a first argument of type 'oesac.Models.oesacEntities_connection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

(_db.Courses is underlined, just Courses has the underline)

```
//SEARCH BY COURSE TITLE
var courses = (from m in _db.Courses select m);
```

=======================

The Entity Container Name is:
"oesacEntities_connection"

It has 2 tables, Courses and Sponsors, and refreshes tables when I right click in .edmx window and select "Update Model From Database".
So database is there and VS 2010 sees it.
But for some reason there is a disconnect in referencing all this.
If I breeze through the popup after the errors that says "would you like to continue" I get a webpage with this error:

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'oesac.MvcApplication'.

Source Error:

Line 1:  <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="oesac.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>

And this is what is in Global.asax.cs:

```
namespace oesac
{


    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();
```

I'm thinking if it was snake it would have bit me. But a little too new at this MVC dreamworld.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if someone else understands this better I can give them the green checkmark for correct answer. However, a friend at work said sometimes with EF you just have to wipe the slate clean and add a new Entity Framework class. And not get too clever. I had changed the names of the tables in VS 2010 .edmx file like it says you can and somehow the Gremlins took over.

Friend at work and 2 other people came to realize this after pulling out all their hair on one of there first major MVC projects.

And, yes, I did try all the mumbo jumbo of "Update Model From Database" right click in the .edmx in VS.

Comment: mumbo jumbo... lol... That phrase gives away the problem.  You don't actually understand what the UI is doing when you update from database, and thus you don't know when you are messing something up.  This would have been a great idea, if you were using Version Control.  After you regenerated your database, compare the previous and new contexts and see what the difference was...

Comment: Well, in VS .edmx view I had 2 tables that I aliased. tblCourses became Courses. tblSponsors became Sponsors.
However, when looking at the Model Browser and Entities it said one was tblCourses and one was Sponsors. So, there it was, but I couldn't change either with or without version control.